# R regex for everything between LAST backslash and last dot

Tags: regex, r

```
full.path = 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\Data\my_file.csv'
```

I can't figure out the right regex to be left with only

```
essential.name = 'my_file'
```

I'm afraid I keep on failing on encoding correctly **the last backslash**

Comment: Your input `full.path` is not working on windows.  I think you need two backslashes

Comment: This first line returns an error for me. I'd recommend that you use forward slashes.

Comment: `^.*\\([^.]*)[.].*$` But why using a regex ?

Comment: Thanks @Tensibai, how would you grep the desired output otherwise? I need the regular expression to use as argument for sub

Comment: See @akrun answer, use functions aimed at parsing path and filenames. Regexes are not the best way here, there's a lot of pitfall behind (filenames with a dot inside, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the `basename` and `file_path_sans_ext` (from `tools`) to extract the file name

```
tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(full.path))
#[1] "my_file"
```

---

Or if we need `regex`, use `gsub`

```
gsub(".*\\\\|\\..*$", "", full.path)
#[1] "my_file"
```

#### data

```
full.path = 'C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\Data\\my_file.csv'
```

Answer (score 4):

A platform-independent regex solution can also look like

```
> full.path = 'C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\Data\\my_file.csv'
> sub(".*\\\\([^.]*).*", "\\1", full.path)
[1] "my_file"
```

See [online R demo](https://ideone.com/zWYAez).

*Details*:

- `.*` - any 0+ characters as many as possible up to the last...
- `\\\\` - a literal `\` symbol
- `([^.]*)` - Group 1 capturing 0+ characters other than a dot
- `.*` - and the rest of the characters up to its end.

The `\\1` just inserts the contents of the Group 1 into the result.

Comment: Truly speaking, the more correct regex for the current OP requirements is `sub(".*\\\\(.*?)(?:\\.[^.]*)?$", "\\1", full.path)`. It will support file names with dots in them, while still allowing file names with no dots.