# RegEx to extract text between last forwardslash and specific string (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex, filenames

I am trying to extract a specific string between the last forward slash and a dot without success. I tried the ones on this solution: [R regex for everything between LAST backslash and last dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39512284/r-regex-for-everything-between-last-backslash-and-last-dot)

Here is an example of the full string:

`48494,Test,0000,Color,,,htps://url/test/testing/bb/1/dim/green.png`

I want to extract `"green"`, which is always between last slash and the last dot. I also tried the following regex:

`([^\/]+$)`

But this one selects *everything* after backslash. I want to remove everything after last dot in order to pick just the color.

**EDIT:** This question is different from [Get Filename from URL and Strip File Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638163/get-filename-from-url-and-strip-file-extension) because I am looking for a regex to use by the match method not replace.

I can't use replace, because the whole system is prepared to use match operator and can't be changed, since a lot of rules already exist for other scenarios using regex expression with match. The engine uses match, not replace.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43638372/3832970 might work. There are other similar solutions there.

Comment: Convering R answer from [the post you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39512284/r-regex-for-everything-between-last-backslash-and-last-dot) to JS: `s.replace(/.*\/|\..*/g, '')`

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew almost there, that selects everything to the last backslash and the last part of the .png, 2 matches, i want what is inside , the green , so maybe negating that?

Comment: What do you mean? `"htps://url/test/testing/bb/1/dim/green.png".replace(/.*\/|\..*/g, '')` = > `green`

Comment: I am using match not replace, that matches the boundaries of the green (before and after the green), what I need is a regex to match the green, do you know how? thank you!

Comment: Why `match` if you can use many other simpler solutions? Besides, there is no such requirement in your question. Please edit it, add all the requirements, add your code and explain what is wrong

Comment: "*I am looking for a regex to use by the match method not replace*" - so, high time to switch to using `replace` or `split` with `replace` since it is easier to use, read and maintain. Why `match`?

Comment: I cant use replace, because the whole system is prepared to use match operator and can't be changed, since a lot of rules already exist for other cases scenarios using regex expression used by the match. The engine uses match, not replace. I will edit the question. thanks

Comment: That is important to mention it at the very beginning that you can't modify the code. Try `/[^\/]+(?=\.[^\/.]*$)/`

Comment: Sorry I thought about just asking for a regex , you are right about it .

Comment: Yeah that works at least on https://regexr.com/, I am not sure it will work on our system because it uses a lookahead right? And not sure it will work on our engine, need to test.

Comment: If it is JavaScript, it will work. If it is RE2 it won't. What is the system? A known one or some in-house?

Comment: I tested using theWholeString.match(new RegExp('[^\/]+(?=\.[^\/.]*$)', 'gi')) and it returns 'green.pn' its weird . the system is built on nodejs

Comment: Why use constructor? Use a regex literal. If you just pass a string pattern to the regex engine via some input field, just use `[^/]+(?=\.[^/.]*$)`. In a RegExp constructor, you should remember that a backslash must be doubled, else, it will be lost (`"[^\/]+(?=\.[^\/.]*$)"` = `"[^/]+(?=.[^/.]*$)"` that matches `green.pn`, correct, because `.` matches any char)

Comment: So what do you want? A string pattern? Or a string/regex literal to be used inside a JS code?

Comment: Yeah you are right using [^\\/]+(?=\\.[^\\/.]*$) it worked like a charm, please add it as an answer if you would like, so I will be pleased to accept it :)

Comment: No need to escape `/` inside a constructor. Slashes are not special chars.

Comment: without the double escaping like I mention in my previous comment it returns green.pn, so I will use the double escaping \\ thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
/[^\/]+(?=\.[^\/.]*$)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XJcoWB/1).

**Details**

- `[^\/]+` - 1+ chars other than `/`
- `(?=\.[^\/.]*$)` - a positive lookahead that requires `.` and then 0+  chars other than `.` and `/` to the end of the string immediately to the right of the current location. Since lookaheads are zero width assertions the text matched with the lookahead is not added to the overall match.

Note that in JS code, you should mind the use of backslashes inside RegExp constructor and inside regex literals: use double backslashes inside the former and single backslashes in the latter, `/a\/b\d/` = `new RegExp("a/b\\d")` (the slashes are not special regex metacharacters and need no escaping).

JS demo:

```js
var s = "48494,Test,0000,Color,,,htps://url/test/testing/bb/1/dim/green.png";

console.log(s.match(new RegExp("[^/]+(?=\\.[^/.]*$)")));
console.log(s.match(/[^\/]+(?=\.[^\/.]*$)/));
```